# Explanation of UI Component Grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, layout, uicomponent

Is there a good explaination and/or sample of the bare minimum configuration needed to create a UI Component Grid in Magento 2?

I know there are myriad core components, such as

```
./vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml
```

However, these XML files are expansive, and there's little explanation about what each node does, and how you'd use this to build a grid from scratch.

There's also this [sample module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sampleform_form.xml), but it

1. Appears to be fore a form
2. Lacks any context/explanation about what each node does

I'm looking for the "getting started" information that would let me build a grid for my own CRUD model collection.

Comment: Not quite worth a full answer -- but my UI Component series is good place to start: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/#magento-2-ui

Comment: Adding more to this explanation Here are the some links which are providing some quite good info about the UI Component in the Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/creat-a-ui-form-in-magento-2.html https://www.cmarix.com/blog/key-steps-to-create-a-simple-ui-component-in-magento-2/ https://magecomp.com/blog/create-ui-component-grid-and-form-magento-2/

Answer (score 192, accepted):

**[EDIT 3 Oct 2018]**

Update for links to devdocs:
2.0 - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-listing-grid.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary.html

2.1 - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-listing-grid.html

2.2 - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-listing-grid.html

**[EDIT 21 Jan 2016]**

As of 20/01/2016 magento2 devdocs has been updated with extended documentation of UI components. I have not checked it extensively but they may contain more information than the response I gave few days ago, so in the interest of your time you may want to see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-library/ui-library-secondary.html

**[/EDIT]**

I have been working with Magento2 for over a month now and this is what I noticed about the new way of creating grids.

Magento 2 UI grid component

1) layout file inside `Company/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/routerid_controller_action.xml` define grid as uiComponent with:

2) uiComponent is defined in `Company/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/listing_name.xml` file. File name must be the same as uiComponent name used in layout file. The structure of the file may seem pretty complex at first sight but as always these are some repeating nodes. To make it simple lets slice it. Main node of the component file is `<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">`. It is fixed and I believe it requires namespace location attribute. Next there are typically 4 nodes inside `<listing />` node: `<argument />`, `<dataSource />`, `<container />` and `<columns />`. This is however not a strict setup as `<argument />` node might be duplicated to provide more configuration or `<container />` as in cms page listing that adds "sticky" container for some reason.

The first node is `<argument />`. This node defines data for the component. Usually you need to provide something like this:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">listing_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Item</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

`<argument />` node requires attribute `name`. In this case `data` defines basic information about the component. It contains multiple `<item />` node for each specific part of configuration. `js_config` tells the component where are provider of the data and dependencies in the listing xml configuration (which I think is converted into javascript hash). `provider` value consist of listing name used in layout file and uniqure data source name that will be used later. In those listings I checked in magento `provider` and `deps` are the same. I am not sure what is use of having this different. `spinner` takes name of the node where columns of the grid are defined. `buttons` allows to add buttons to the top of the grid. In most cases it would be just `Add new` button. Buttons have few elements: `name` used as element id, `label` is what the button says, `class` is the button class and `url` is the link to which it points. Asteriks is replaced by the portion of current url. Other possible `<item />` nodes for button are: `id`, `title`, `type` (reset, submit or button), `onclick` (instead of `url`, it has precedence), `style`, `value`, `disabled`. Button element is rendered by `Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Button` class.

Next we have `<dataSource />` node:

```
<dataSource name="listing_name_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">UniqueNameGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">listing_name_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">database_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">request_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

`name` used in `<dataSource />` node must match the one used in `argument/js_config/provider` and `argument/js_config/deps`. Next node defines which class is responsible for preparing data for the grid. `class` argument requires unique name that will be matched in `di.xml`. `primaryFieldName` relates to the database primary column and `requestFieldName` to the variable in http requests. They may be equal but don't have to, CMS page listing uses `page_id` as `primaryFieldName` and `id` as `requestFieldName`. `update_url` refers to the entry point where ajax calls for filtering and sorting are send. Second argument in `<dataSource />` refers to javascript file that handles js part of sending and processing ajax calls for the grid. The default file is `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/provider.js`.

Another node is `<container />`.

```
<container name="listing_top"> ... </container>
```

As it contains a lot of data let me divide it as well. Its children are the parts of the entire page. First child `<argument />`:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

It defines knockout template responsible for handling the layout and all actions and by default points to `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/toolbar.html`

Next node is (or can be) `<bookmark />`

```
<bookmark name="bookmarks">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">listing_name</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</bookmark>
```

This node adds bookmark feature to the grid. It allows admin to set up different "profiles" of the grid which displays different columns. Thanks to that you can add all columns from the table to the grid and let the user decide which information are relevant to him. `namespace` must match name used in layout file.

Another node is `<component />`

```
<component name="columns_controls">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_columns</item>
            </item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</component>
```

We have 3 values to configure here. First is `provider` which follows the pattern [listing_name_from_layout].[listing_name_from_layout].[listing_columns_node_name] (like in node listing/argument/spinner). `component` refers to js file that displays grid and by default points to `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/controls/columns.js` which uses template `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/controls/columns.html`. The last item is `displayArea` which defines where column controls need to be displayed. It refers to `getRegion('dataGridActions')` in file defined in `container/argument/config/template` (default: `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/toolbar.html`).

Next node is `<filterSearch />`

```
<filterSearch name="fulltext">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name_data_source</item>
            <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</filterSearch>
```

This node adds full text search into the page. It is located above the grid as single text input field with "Search by keyword" as a placeholder. I am not sure what options are possible here as I didn't play with this much but listing_filters_chips refers to `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/filters/chips.js` file.

Next node is `<filters />`

```
<filters name="listing_filters">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_columns</item>
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
            </item>
            <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</filters>
```

This node defines configuration for column filtering that is visible after clicking "Filters" button at the top right above the grid. `columnsProvider` follows similar structure as previous nodes, so [listing_name_from_layout].[listing_name_from_layout].[listing_columns_node_name]. `storegeConfig` goes like [listing_name_from_layout].[listing_name_from_layout].[container_node_name][bookmark_node_name]. In `templates` item node you can define which files are used to render specific filter options. In this case only select is defined and it uses `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/ui-select.js` as `component` and `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/filters/elements/ui-select.html` as knockout template. Look into `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element` to see other possibilities. Only select is defined here to override default values: `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js` and `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/filters/elements/select.html`. Default values for filters and other nodes are defined in `Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml`.

Next node is `<massAction />` and allows to add mass action select to the grid

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_columns.ids</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">database_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <action name="delete">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/massDelete"/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
    <action name="change_status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">change_status</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change Status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="actions" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status\Options</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change Status</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to change status for selected feed(s)?</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </action>
</massaction>
```

`name` argument should be unique. First child node `<argument />` defines basic data. `provider` follows the same structure as other nodes and refers to columns node name and its ids column. This column will hold checkboxes with selected items for the mass action to process. `component` defines what file is used to render and handle the mass action. Default value is `Magento_Ui/js/grid/massactions` (points to `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/massactions.js`). You can use `Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions` to add tree like structure. In the above case I use it to add "Change status" action which shows "enable" and "disable" options. 
After `<argument />` node you can add as many `<action />` nodes as many actions you want to have. Each `<action />` node follows similar scheme. In the first case (delete action) node requires unique name. Then `argument` contains configuration where `label` is what is visible in select option, `url` endpoint to send data and `confirm` adds confirmation modal before send. In case of "Change status" action `url` in first `argument` node is ommited as urls are provided per status by class defined in second `argument` node. The class should implement Zend\Stdlib\JsonSerializable interface. Check `Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options` as a reference.

Finally in the `<container />` node we have `<paging />` node that defines pagination.

```
<paging name="listing_paging">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
            </item>
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_columns.ids</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</paging>
```

Structure for `provider` and `selectProvider` should be clear now.

And the last node for basic grid is `<columns />`. It contains all definition of columns that are available for use by the admin. Node is defined as

```
<columns name="listing_columns"> ... </columns>
```

and the name attribute is used in other nodes when refers to it. First child is

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
        </item>
        <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
            </item>
            <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">name_listing.name_listing.listing_columns.actions</item>
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

What I did here was only supply correct `provider` values following the scheme used in the listing. `fieldAction` node allows to define action that is fired when clicked on the cell. Default settings call edit action

Next is `<selectionColumns />`

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</selectionsColumn>
```

This node defines column with checkboxes for mass action to use. It names is referred to after dot in several nodes described above.

After that you can add any number of columns in the same format:

```
<column name="name" class="Company\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Model\Source\Type</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Not all most inner items node are necessary. They are defining:

`filter` - filter type of the column. This is used in filters block. Available values are: text, select, dateRange. If select is used `<item name="options">...</item>` will be used as a class that provides options for the filter select

`component` - defines js files which is used to render column. Available options are in `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/*`. select is provided is filter is set to select. For text filter this value is not required.

`dataType` - provides information of data type used for the column value. For select use select as well, for dateRange use date
`bodyTmpl` - defines html file used by knockout to render cell. By default ui/grid/cells/text is used (`Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/cells/text.html`). Other options are located in `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/cells/*` directory. `ui/grid/cells/html` allows to use html content in cell.

`label` - this will be displayed in the column header and filter block

`sortOrder` - ordering

`visible` - whether or not display the column. This can be used to defined columns for bookmarks but do not show them by default.

At the end you can add actions column witch actions available to do for the single item

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Company\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">database_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</actionsColumn>
```

`indexField` refers to column name in the database. Actions class should extends `Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column` and define `prepareDataSource` method. See `Magento/Cms/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php` as a reference

3) to finish the grid we need to define some elements in Company/Module/etc/di.xml

First we define provider class that was used in node `dataSource/class`

```
<virtualType name="UniqueNameGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Company\Module\Model\Resource\Item\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">UniqueNameItemIdFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

`collection` resolves to standard collection class and `filerPool` defines new element:

```
<virtualType name="UniqueNameItemIdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

This evidently has to do something with filtering and searching. For now I always used the default values.

Now we register our data source:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="listing_name_data_source" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Model\Resource\Item\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

In this case node name must match the one used in `<dataSource />` node in listing xml and it resolves not to collection but to GridCollection class. It should extend regular collection class and additionally implement `Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface`.

At the end we configure our grid collection (argument names are rather obvious)

```
<type name="Company\Module\Model\Resource\Item\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">database_table_name</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">name_for_events</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">event_object_name</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Model\Resource\Item</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: [did you get chance to look on my thread](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98262/how-to-extend-inject-this-to-customer-address-in-magento-2)

Comment: This still beats the docs by a long way, as far as I can see.

Comment: 2) uiComponent is defined in Company/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/listing_name.xml. So, basically, the grid component does not work on the frontend ?

Comment: old post I know - but, I've come to this, followed it (thanks btw, definitely one of the most detailed explanations on this out there) but I get an uncaught error in relation to the collectionFactory. specifically the argumentsResolver function. It says argument 2 should be an array but null is given - I've done all the above - but is there anything else I should have done? :)

Comment: Clear cache and var/generation (or generated/code in Magento 2.2.). If this won't help I would check config once again. Make sure `<item name="">` is the same in all elements where it appears (listing_name_data_source). Check if you do not have some typo in the `DataProvider\CollectionFacory` arguments definition either in nodes or in class name.

Comment: **This XML here is out of date.**  Magento 2.2 refactored their XML so it is more readable and gives better type hinting and validation with the XSD.   In essence, instead of `<item name="filter">`, you have a `<filter>` element.  The old XML still works, but may be deprecated in the future.  [Reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/best-practices/semantic_config.html).

Comment: Good to know I will check it out. The reply was made based on 2.0.x edition almost 2 years ago. If you are writing a module that need to hit pre-2.2 releases then this is still more safe option. It will probably be in use for another year before most people will abamdon old versions

Comment: Nice explanation.!!

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-library/ui-library-secondary.html is a dead link now

Comment: @seanbreeden thanks, I updated links to devdocs

Comment: The page http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-library/ui-library-secondary.html is not working.

Comment: @AshishViradiya the updated links are above, under [EDIT 3 Oct 2018] section

Comment: @Zefiryn can you explain why two different types of collection 1) `Company\Module\Model\Resource\Item\Collection` in declaring `dataSource/class` and 2) `Company\Module\Model\Resource\Item\Grid\Collection` while registering data source

Comment: Nicely explained. I am wondering if I can use the same UI component for my different grid. If my columns are repeated, then would make easier to use one UI component to reduce the copy and paste. Any idea on this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286743/use-same-ui-component-for-different-data-source

Comment: I want to change grid collection data. Any idea?

Comment: File name in layout is key to make this works that's where the trouble was for me. it have to have `routerid_controller_action`

Comment: After 4 Years still, this is a Gem! Give this man a Medal!

Answer (score 10):

For grid we need two main files one is ui_component xml and second one is di.xml

I hope you know in layout xml file you need to add uiComponent tag, i.e. -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="test_lists_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

now you need to create a `test_lists_listing.xml` in ui_component folder.

E.g. **app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\adminhtml\ui_component\test_lists_listing.xml**

This file has number of tags

1. `<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">` :- need mention arugemnt like button js etc..
2. `<dataSource name="test_lists_listing_data_source">` :- this block is used to supply data for grids in this one of arguments is `<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ListsGridDataProvider</argument>` which we need to mention in `di.xml` (explained in **di.xml** part)
3. `<container name="listing_top">` :- in this block we mention filters, export, bookmarks (which save data in ui_bookmark table ),massaction, paging,  and fulltext (to do fulltext search in setup or table that column should be fulltext index )
4. `<columns name="test_lists_columns">` :- in this we need mention all column

Last one is in **di.xml**

```
<virtualType name="TestGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>  


<virtualType name="ListsGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">TestGirdFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>  


<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="test_lists_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">testtable</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">test_test_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">test_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

1. TestGirdFilterPool :- mention filters
2. ListsGridDataProvider :- which i mentioned in ui xml for data provider
3. CollectionFactory :- need to mention collection
4. Grid/Collection :- in this we need to pass all params like table name, collection etc.

**app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\adminhtml\ui_component\test_lists_listing.xml**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">test_lists_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Info</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="test_lists_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ListsGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <container name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/search/search</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">

            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>


            <filterSelect name="status">
                <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Sugarcode\Test\Model\Status</argument>
                </argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select...</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterSelect>

        </filters>

        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="test/lists/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns_editor</item>
                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="disable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="test/lists/massDisable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="enable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="test/lists/massEnable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>

        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="test_lists_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="test/lists/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>

                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.test_lists_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>     
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn> 
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>   
         <column name="order_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="filter_index" xsi:type="string">o.increment_id</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>       
        <column name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Sugarcode\Test\Model\Status</item>
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>   


        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Sugarcode\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\TestActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: sortOrder is not working for selectionsColumn. Do not why it is coming at last

Answer (score 9):

### The Supplement of Top Answer

The top answer is great, I follow it to create a listing page. But, **it has a problem**:

> When you apply filter, then removing filter, **same row content will repeat in the whole page grid**.

### Solution

In the `<dataSource />` node, below `<item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>`, add the content:

```
<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
</item>
```

`entity_id` is the primary key for the listing collection.

Comment: entity_id is the default value for data-storage.js, so why you have to define in xml?

Comment: I tested that you have to add it only if is different from entity_id.

Comment: in a Grid using \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Filesystem like in \Magento\Backup\Model\Fs\Collection the "primaryFieldName" is id not entity_id

Comment: @LucScu You are right. I just give a example `entity_id` for explanation. Some official modules or custom modules didn't use `entity_id` as __primary key__.

Comment: You did well to remind it

Answer (score 5):

I found @Zefiryn's answer very helpful and a great way to get started without reading the full documentation from Magento.

That said I didn't get things quite working following these answers. What's more, once you have a listing page working, you'll immediately want the rest of a CRUD interface.

I found a [sample module on github](https://github.com/ashsmith/magento2-blog-module-tutorial). Starting out with this thread for orientation then porting / hacking code from the sample plugin turned out to be the quickest way to get a CRUD interface against a custom table.