# Can any one tell me how exactly Magento 2 grid works ?

Tags: magento2

I have integrated properly magento grid from one tutorial but I am not getting how it is structured, what are the things are require to make grid work ?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Check UI component explanation: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Most elements of interface consist of several UI components, which described in xml in ui_component folder more infop about UI components there
*http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary.html*