# ui_component form or php form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, uicomponent

What should  i follow `ui_component form` or `php form`  so my module can work on all **magento 2** versions. Or Should i create two  modules so they will work on **magento 2.0** and **magento 2.1**? 
Any one else have a better solution for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Magento 2.0 totally supports UI Component form, it's not a 2.1 feature only** so I suggest you use the UI Component ;)

Also you can find the benefits of using the UI components here: [Magento 2: what are the benefits of using UI grid components over the standard Grid.php?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/113924/2380)

Comment: i tested it was not working with **magento2.0**  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135087/adding-save-button-with-ui-component-not-working

Comment: @QaisarSatti you probably have another error somewhere, refer to the sample ui component form module here: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent

Comment: funny thing first i tested this free module but the `save` and other button are not loading then i added button from block follow the magento `m2.1` i got this error it solved after move to `m2.1`

Comment: @QaisarSatti try switching to 2.0.9 instead

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 2.1** you should go with **Ui Component** for grid and if you don't have any customization in your form then you can use Ui component for form too, but if you have any customization or any changes in buit-in form input types you can use normal php form.
but as Magento 2.1 has lots of benefits I prefer to use Ui component
for more benefits and use you can refere [MagentoDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ui_component` you can do lot of customization with `ui_component` I used to do custom php forms, but once you realize the power of `ui_component` I'm sure you'll use it after

You can extend your ui_component elements so you can do whatever, you need.