# Can create grid like the way of magento 1x in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, backend

Sometime i want to create a grid in backend like the way in magento 1. Should i use that way or complete move to ui way? I heard somewhere that old way soon will deprecated! Is it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Magento 1 way of creating a grid class and defining the columns and collection within that is still possible, but not recommended. Best practice is to use a UI Component. Do things right.

Magento will be moving all core grids to UI components over time; they've changed a lot of them already in the recently-released 2.1.

See here for an extensive walkthrough of creating a custom grid via UI components: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97891/1905