# magento2 - Study of ui component xml tags

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

magento2 use of ui component tags

I gone through UI component explanation link 
[Explanation of UI Component Grid in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2)

its explains lot.

Also in core ui component, I have found the item tag with observers

```
<item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="filters" xsi:type="object">Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\Component\Listing\AssociatedProduct\Filters</item>
</item>
```

I like to use observers item node in my model.

Is that any source available to get more information about item node declaration

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 validates all XML files against XML Schema Definition, or XSD, files. That basically means that every possible node of every type used in a XML file is available and can be referenced.

Let's use `UI component` for example. Depending on how you installed Magento, you can drill down to `magento2ce/vendor/magento/module-ui/etc/` or `magento2ce/app/code/Magento/Ui/etc/` where you will find a few XSD files. Starting with `ui_components.xsd` take some time to view the contents of each.

Visit the [Magento 2 Github repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1/app/code/Magento/Ui/etc) to view those files online.