# Disable filter for column in Magento 2 grid component

Tags: magento2, grid, filter, column

There is a great explanation of the [Grid Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2) but I cannot find how to disable filter for a column. I need only ordering for my column because value for this column is calculated.

```
    <column name="prxgt_is_in_odoo">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is in Odoo</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Answer (score 4):

It is simple, just comment or remove "filter" node in column definition:

```
    <column name="prxgt_is_in_odoo">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>-->
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is in Odoo</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```