# Magento2 module grid page issue

Tags: magento2

I am creating a module in magento 2 and I am getting this error on grid page of my module. Can anyone help me sorting this out.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:41:"Class PageGridDataProvider does not exist";i:1;s:9257:"#0 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('PageGridDataPro...')
#1 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('PageGridDataPro...')
#2 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('PageGridDataPro...')
#3 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('PageGridDataPro...', Array)
#4 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Argument/Interpreter/ConfigurableObject.php(60): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('PageGridDataPro...', Array)
#5 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Argument\Interpreter\ConfigurableObject->evaluate(Array)
#6 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#7 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(188): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#8 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(191): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->evaluateComponentArguments(Array)
#9 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(172): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->evaluateComponentArguments(Array)
#10 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('grid_record_gri...')
#11 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('grid_record_gri...', NULL, Array)
#12 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'grid_record_gri...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#13 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#14 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#15 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#16 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#17 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#19 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#20 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#21 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#22 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
#23 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Netzwelt_Winclo...')
#24 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/app/code/Netzwelt/Winclosepopup/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/index.php(33): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Netzwelt_Winclo...')
#25 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/var/generation/Netzwelt/Winclosepopup/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/index/Interceptor.php(24): Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\Index->execute()
#26 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor->execute()
#27 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#30 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Netzwelt\\Winclo...', 'dispatch', Object(Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#31 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Netzwelt\\Winclo...', 'dispatch', Object(Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#34 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/var/generation/Netzwelt/Winclosepopup/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/index/Interceptor.php(39): Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#37 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#40 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#41 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#44 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#46 /home/pc-new/phproot/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#47 {main}";s:3:"url";s:108:"/magento2/admin_4pxpx3/grid/grid/index/key/d7e8da4f29df0f26df4b560e4831c8440e9384b5fa106efbd8b65c23f91aea60/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/magento2/index.php";}
```

Comment: You didn't created `PageGridDataProvider` as error mentioned

Comment: Check this answer for details info on how to create grid in admin http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2/97891#97891

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution for my problem. If anyone has any other option then please share.

**Solution**: Replace `PageGridDataProvider` with `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider`

in `app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component` folder files.

Comment: I think you can update your answer in your question with marked as SOLVED

Comment: Thank you Atul you have given nice answer and saved my time...