# Explanation of module_grid.xml in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, xml

I am referring to the tutorial here to create my admin module:
http://www.advancedcheckout.com/blog/magento2-tutorial-how-to-create-admin-grid-in-magento2.html/

I'm not able to understand 2 things:

1. How are we defining our table name and columns
2. What does the elements in module_grid.xml mean and what has to be written inside each tags

Can anyone please share their views on this one?

Comment: don't follow that tutorial. It's outdated. The admin grids will be moved to the ui component system. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-listing-grid.html

Comment: I was going through one of yours posts ( http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2 ), but was not able to understand a few things, so I referred that tutorial.

Comment: that's not my post

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I wrote your post, but still referring to it I was stuck in a few problems and was not able to understand a few things