# Get Base Url Or Dynamic Url In view Js or html files

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, javascript

I figure it out to get dynamic url in the front end if I need I can simply define `mage/url` and the use it as `url.build('<Modulename>/<controllername>/<action>/')`

When I tried the same thing for the backend it didn't return me the expected result.

It gave the the current url and append the path which I had given.

Can anyone explain how this works out. Do I need to define the baseUrl somewhere ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Khoa for his explanation what I wanted to achieve is in my admin form I am calling an external url with ajax. I was using a static path so I wanted it dynamically. So here's what I have done.

My Layout XML File

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
                <uiComponent name="namespace_modulename_form"/>
                <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Edit" name="edit" template="Namespace_Modulename::edit.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Layout Phtml File I defined the baseUrl.

```
    <script>
        require([
            'mage/url'
        ], function(url) {
            return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAdminBaseUrl();?>');
        })
    </script>
```

My block file which returns the base url

```
<?php

namespace Namespcae\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml;

class Edit extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_configReader;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader $configReader
    ) {
        $this->_configReader = $configReader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getAdminBaseUrl(){
        $config = $this->_configReader->load();
        $adminSuffix = $config['backend']['frontName'];
        return $this->getBaseUrl() . $adminSuffix . '/';
    }
}
```

Now in my js files I can use it as.

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'mage/url'
], function (Abstract, url) {
    'use strict';

    return Abstract.extend({
        url.build('namespace_module/controllername/action/');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Just Do That Only in js file

```
define(['mage/url'], 
  function (url) {
   'use strict';
    var url = url.build('<modulename>/<controllername>/<actionname>');
});
```

Result will be:

```
http://ip_address/<modulename>/<controllername>/<actionname>
```

Comment: This will not give me the same result In backend. So need to define the base the url in block first

Comment: But in ur question u mention that u want **URL** in **js** so this will  helpful. Now tell me in which file do u want **URL**. Is your problem solved or not?

Comment: How we get base url of site using url.build() function?

Comment: using this -> define(['mage/url']

Answer (score 7):

The most important thing we need to know: **We need to set base url for `url.build('<Modulename>/<controllername>/<action>/')`**:

*lib/web/mage/url.js*

```
        setBaseUrl: function (url) {
            baseUrl = url;
        },
        build: function(path) {
            if (path.indexOf(baseUrl) != -1) {
                return path;
            }
            return baseUrl + path;
        }
```

Basically, there are two places where to set the base url:

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml`
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/shipping.phtml`

```
return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>');
```

**So, in your admin, you have to set the admin base url.**

Comment: Ok I get that. But talking about admin forms, where I need this to be implemented. My form is created using ui component so how Can I set the url as it has been defined in onepage or shipping ?

Comment: Hello, you can explain more details about your issue. About Ui component: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2