# How to link to images from a Javascript file

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, theme, media-images

I have created a custom JavaScript file in a `Magento 2.1.7` theme that serves a different logo depending on the month.

The .js file is in `app/design/` inside the theme’s `/web/js/` folder. The logos are in the theme’s `/web/images/` folder.

**The .js contains switch/case code** with relative links to the images `../images/logo1.png` etc.

I assumed that once deployed and the files had moved to **pub/static** that it would work, but it didn’t. The images aren’t being transferred from the theme `web/images` folder to the `pub/static` images folder.

I have got it working by using links from the root to `/pub/media/logos/logo1.png` but are there better ways of achieving this? I would appreciate help. I’m assuming that there aren’t any directives with a shortcut to the pub/media folder that can be used in JavaScript?

Comment: Use `url.build()` function in js to get url path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the URL in your PHTML file and pass it through to your JS like so:

**PHTML**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "yourJsAliasHere": {
                "imageUrl": "<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image-name.jpg'); ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**JS**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function(config) {
        alert(config.imageUrl);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible without changes to the theme's phtml? I always try to avoid making changes to keep my upgrades easier and usually only create a module for more larger functions. The part of the js with the path I’m currently using is…
case 8: case 9: case 10:
            logoimg = "/pub/media/logos/logo-autumn.png";

Comment: You could do it [this way](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139071/get-base-url-or-dynamic-url-in-view-js-or-html-files) but it isn't much better than hardcoding it, personally I find following best practices to be better than using 'dirtier' methods just for the sake of not overriding a template.