# Can anyone explain what is form component in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.1

I have a question that "What is form component?".

I just want post a form to URL (ex: localhost/admincustomer/processing) in admin without DataProvider, but it didn't. I don't need storage DB or add/edit DB, just post.

I'm using form component but it need DataProvider. Please help me!

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-form.html

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh no, it's form component not grid/list UI component

Comment: Yes, however, I think there are some helpful info: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2

Comment: Yes, I read all of it. But couldn't find answer for my question

Comment: I think the doc should be updated with more details about Ui component.

Comment: I see you marked your question 2.1.1. You should update to 2.1.2. A lot of forms (like cms forms and others) are converted to xml based forms built with ui components. Learning Magentos' source is a great way to understand ui components