# Magento 2 : how to add custom grid using ui-component in admin Form Tab

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, adminform

I want to have a custom Grid in Admin Form tab using `ui_component` .

Here is my Grid `ui_component` for tab fieldset.

```
<fieldset name="assign_applicants">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Applicants</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="assign_products_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Package_Name\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Job\AssignApplicants</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 6):

In your `<fieldset>` section you could use [`<insertListing>`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-insertlisting.html).

```
    <fieldset name="assign_applicants">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Applicants</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <insertListing>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">applicants_form_listing</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </insertListing>
    </fieldset>
```

In the `ns` config you specify the listing UI component's name. 
Then you define this component separately in the `view/adminhtml/ui_component/applicants_form_listing.xml` and describe what should be in the grid (you can check [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2) for details).

Comment: It is working but it is not send data to controller.

Comment: @dan.Kocherga how do i filter applicants_form_listing grid content based on ui form id?