# Mass status in admingrid: Ui form

Tags: php, grid, magento2.2, massaction

I have created Admingrid and associate UI form. I need to change the Status for all the items using Massaction. Any one know Please suggest me.. 
Uigrid.xml

```
 <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">ox_homeslider_post_listing.ox_homeslider_post_listing.ox_homeslider_post_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="homeslider/post/massdelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Slides</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected Slides?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
         <action name="status">
            <settings>
                <type>status</type>
                <label translate="true">Change status</label>
                <actions>
                    <action name="0">
                        <type>enable</type>
                        <label translate="true">Enable</label>
                        <url path="homeslider/post/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">1</param>
                        </url>
                    </action>
                    <action name="1">
                        <type>disable</type>
                        <label translate="true">Disable</label>
                        <url path="homeslider/post/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">2</param>
                        </url>
                    </action>
                </actions>
            </settings>
        </action>
    </massaction>
```

Comment: Check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2/97306. It explain massaction in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your massaction in your uicomponent grid.

Inside  `listingToolbar>` tag you can define `<massaction>` as many mass action you want.

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">listing_name.listing_name.listing_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected entries?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
</listingToolbar>
```

`<item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>` defines the primary key which you will get in your controller.

`<item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/massDelete"/>` defines the path of your controller where you can call your model and perform mass action on it. You need to create controller for same.

**Update For Mass Status Update**

You need to define your mass controller

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory; // Define your collection here
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class MassDisable
 */
class MassStatus extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;


    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $statusValue = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->setStatus($statusValue);
            $item->save();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been modified.', $collection->getSize()));

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already done MassDelete function. Now need to do change status which will be updated for all items listing in grid. I

Comment: I have updated my question .Please refer that

Comment: I need grid format for mass status. But in above, you have given grid code for mass delete

Answer (score 3):

I have added  **tree-massactions and display area** in **grid** structure. After that Mass actions works fine.
Here I have given **grid** structure for mass actions.
Hope it helps.

**grid.xml for Massactions**

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">ox_homeslider_post_listing.ox_homeslider_post_listing.ox_homeslider_post_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="homeslider/post/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Slides</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected Slides?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>


            <action name="status">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change status</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="homeslider/post/massstatus">
                            <param name="status">1</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="homeslider/post/massstatus">
                            <param name="status">0</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
```