# How can i create admin grid using layout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to create admin grid in Magento 2. if you have any article or blog then please share 
Thank you

Comment: You can use search function on this stack: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create simple extension using this blog. It's best blog for creating module.

> http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/magento-2-sample-extension-for-beginners-318