# Magento 2 Form UiComponent Explaination

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

I have found very good in detailed explaination of the magento ui_component grid in below question :
[Explanation of UI Component Grid in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2)

I want to know about the form ui_component in detailed as below point

- Defining DataProvider is Mandatory for custom extension.
- In `fieldset` > `field` passing `source` argument, what is the use of that?

  ```
  <field name="id" formElement="input">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="source" xsi:type="string">cms</item> <!-- what is the use of this ?? -->
          </item>
      </argument>
  </field>
  ```

How to Use `wyswyig` editor ??

```
<formElements>
    <wysiwyg>
        <settings>
            <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
        </settings>
    </wysiwyg>
</formElements>
```

How `fileUploader` work ?

```
<field name="image" sortOrder="25" formElement="fileUploader">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">post</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</elementTmpl>
        <dataType>string</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Image</label>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <dataScope>image</dataScope>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
        </validation>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <fileUploader>
            <settings>
                <uploaderConfig>
                    <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="blog/post_image/upload" />
                </uploaderConfig>
                <previewTmpl>[Namespace]_[ModuleName]/image-preview</previewTmpl>
            </settings>
        </fileUploader>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Other points from your sides are most welcome.