# What is the flow of execution of UI COMPONENT in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically, I want to know the flow of execution how UI component render?

Comment: Please follow below link for detailed Ui component flow in Magento 2 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2

Comment: I have gone through it and here the explanation of UI component is available.But i want to know the flow which tag compile first like data source,argument etc.

Answer (score 3):

For Ui-Form

```
<form> -> <datasource> -> <fieldset> -> <field>
```

For Ui-listing

```
<listing> -> <datasource> -> <listingtoolbar> -> <columns> -> <column>
```

this is the flow of loading UI components tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot .You save my day

Comment: please verify so it can also help out others