# Magento2 - How to display sales order table data to admin grid?

Tags: magento2

HI I want to know that i need to create a module that will show the report of sold product and their generated revenue.

so I want to know that can we fetch custom table data and display it in admin grid anyone have any idea about it kindly please provide some guidance.

I think I needs to fetch this table data

`sales_order`

[image]

Comment: This is related to creating a admin grid. Refer [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html) to do the same.

Comment: hi @pramod have you checked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a module using this link [click here](http://module.m2s.emiprotechnologies.com/)

OR [Download Sample Module](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FB1bxTn74aYS61zHPxgmHt6pMK4LdwOu?usp=sharing)

and put name like this

[image]

now replace this files

**Emipro/Custom/Model/ResourceModel**

**Job.php**

```
<?php

namespace Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Job extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('sales_order', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

**Emipro/Custom/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


    <!--    For Job     -->
    <virtualType name="EmiproCustomJobFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="EmiproCustomJobFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Job\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">EmiproCustomJobFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Job\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">job_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Job</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="emipro_custom_job_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Job\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>


</config>
```

**Emipro/Custom/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

**emipro_custom_job_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2 -->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">custom_job_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="emipro_custom_job_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">EmiproCustomJobFilterPool</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.custom_job_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>

        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.custom_job_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.custom_job_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>

                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterSelect name="store_id">
                <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</argument>
                </argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                        <item name="captionValue" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterSelect>

        </filters>

        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.custom_job_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>

            <action name="is_delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="custom/index/massDelete">
                        </item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>

        </massaction>

        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.custom_job_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>

    <columns name="custom_job_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.custom_job_columns</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">emipro_custom_job_listing.emipro_custom_job_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>


        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="state">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">state</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

Now Add Simple Column to this listing file. column name must be match with the **sales_order** table column name.

Column name in table **sales_order** must be match with column name

```
<column name="table_column_name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Lable Name</item>
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

[image]

Comment: column name must be match with the sales_order table column name. can you please explain this

Comment: is there anyway to filter a order grid as to show pending order  status only show in the grid

Comment: open this file Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Job\Grid\Collection and add this function

    public function _beforeLoad()
    {
     // add here to filter your status
        $this->addFieldToFilter("status", "pending");
        return $this;
    }