# How to display sales_order (only pending orders) grid in custom module

Tags: sales-order, grid, order-grid

How we can display sales_order grid in custom module with only pending status.

For now I display sales_order_grid using ui component. I only want to display pending orders in this grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add filter in ui component dataSource tag
**uicomponent.xml**

```
<dataSource name="vtn_unexportedorder_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vtn_unexportedorder_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="status" xsi:type="string">pending</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

In above code added filter_url_params and apply filter where status equals to pending

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="status" xsi:type="string">pending</item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using This link you can create Admin grid. [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/305429/82670)  Or You can [Download Module](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FB1bxTn74aYS61zHPxgmHt6pMK4LdwOu?usp=sharing) and modify it.

You can change You table name and primary key from below file.

**Emipro/Custom/Model/ResourceModel**

**Job.php**

```
<?php

namespace Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Job extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Table_Name', 'Primary_Key_Name');
    }
}
```

After In **emipro_custom_job_listing.xml** file at **Emipro/Custom/view/adminhtml/ui_component** you need to change column name also.

Now your Grid is ready now you need only modify one file which is give below:

Update **Collection.php** at **Emipro/Custom/Model/ResourceModel/Job/Grid**

```
<?php

namespace Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Job\Grid;

use Emipro\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Job\Collection as JobCollection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document as JobModel;

class Collection extends JobCollection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    protected $aggregations;

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = JobModel::class,
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }
    
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }
    
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function _beforeLoad()
    {
        parent::_beforeLoad();
        $this->addFieldToFilter("status", "pending");
        return $this;
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but for now I create custom uicomponent but getting all orders. So is there a way to add condition in custom ResoureModel ? 
I have created custom ResourceModel and call core sales_order_grid table

Comment: you can refere my above module and update file it's works. Emipro/Custom/Model/ResourceModel/Job/Grid/Collection.php file are add into di.xml also please check my module.

Comment: IN _beforeLoad method is responsible for filter you grid data.

Comment: Not filtering status=pending, get all the table data

Comment: Please share your di.xml and collection.php file.

Comment: I got issue solve just added filter in uicomponent