# How to get the Id from Database while Edit functionality in magento 2 grid

Tags: database, grid, magento2.2.2, edit

I have created custom admin grid(without ui component). While edit action it needs to get id from DB to display the existing data in form.
**Grid.php**

```
$this->addColumn(
                'edit', [
            'header' => __('Edit'),
            'type' => 'action',

            'actions' => [
                [
                    'caption' => __('Edit'),

                    'url' => $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', ['id' => '1', 'active_tab' => 'upload']),
                ],
//                
            ],
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
                ]
        );
```

In above code, I have given id statically as 1 and it loads the data and displayed in the form, but now I need to get Id from DB dynamically, Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 1):

Add your **'field' => 'id'**  after url. also same in **'getter' => 'getId',**

```
$this->addColumn(
            'edit',
            [
                'header' => __('Action'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => '*/*/edit',
                            'params' => []
                        ],
                        'field' => 'id'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'label' =>  __('Edit'),
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, But it is failed to frame the url for edit action

Comment: @Sri did you change `id` with your column?

Comment: Yes. My grid column id is also  ' id '

Comment: @Sri you check here what you are missing. i can't find any error in this code. .https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86884/how-to-create-admin-grid-in-magento2