# Magento 2 Adminhtml Grid Create like Magento 1

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid

I am new to Magento 2. I want to create a simple Grid where will be 3 columns, ID, Full Name, Email. How can I do that?

As a new comer i found its lil hard for me to create grid using UI Components & XML Layout. I want to create the grid like magento 1, I am familiar with Magento 1.

Can anyone help me with any tutorials??
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> To Create Magento2 Admin Grid Please follow the instructions of below blog:
>   [Simple follow this blog steps]
>   [1]: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html
>
> [Simple follow this blog steps][2]: [How to create Admin Grid in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86884/how-to-create-admin-grid-in-magento2)